# Undefined variable: url in PHP

Tags: php, function, undefined

What am I doing wrong?

I have a error about a undefined variable but it is defined or not?

> Undefined variable: url in /mnt/web121/d2/33/58167933/htdocs/includes/functions.php on line 74

```
$url = "http://www.crime-world.eu";



function logincheck(){
    if (empty($_SESSION['username'])){
        check_legit($url);
        echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.location='index.php';</script>";
        exit();
    }
    check_legit($url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$url` is a global variable. Declare it as global in your function.

```
function logincheck(){
    global $url;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks if works!

Answer (score 0):

$url is not in the function checklogin scope, you can pase it to the function with function parameter or use it as a global variable.